# Create annotation

Tags: iphone, mapkit

how to create annotation without given an y coordinates

Comment: actually i want to display three annotation 1 annotation has its coordinates and rest of two is display near to it so that when we zoom in or out then 3 annotation is display as they display previously means no zoom effect on them.If i give same annotation then there callout is not display properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an annotation ***WITHOUT*** y coordinate!!

And if the callout for annotations with same coordinates is not being displayed properly, that is the problem you should be trying to solve.

Anyways, if you want to show the the three annotations very close, change either x or y by a very very small value.